# Get uploaded document id using JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, rest, file-upload, document-id

I need to get document ID of newly uploaded document using JQuery, any help highly be appreciated.

I'm trying below code which is not working and gives error,

> 404 not found.

```
function getListData() {
var docTitle = jQuery('#fileButton').val();
var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
        "{0}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Private%20Documents')/RootFolder/Files/Get(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
        _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, docTitle);

$.ajax({
    url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: Succeeded,
    error: function Failed() {
    alert('Error!');
}

});
}

function Succeeded(data) {

    var listItemInfo = "";

    $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        listItemInfo += 'ID: ' + value.Id +
            ';';
    });

    alert(listItemInfo);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of docTitle that you are passing? Also, why not use `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')`

Comment: doctitle is the value of uploaded file. I still can't able to retrieve docid for uploaded document.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved; for some reason loop was not working and I used the code below which worked.

```
// Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

    // Send the request and return the response.
    return $.ajax({
        url: fileListItemUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" 
    },
    success: function(data) {
       var dataResults = data.d;

  var ID  = dataResults.ID;
  // alert(ID);

  var  dvelement1 = $("#fileButton1").val();
  var inputNode1 = dvelement1.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")

  $("#T8").append('<div id="del' + dataResults.ID +'"> <li  value="$dvelement" > &nbsp &nbsp'+inputNode1+' &nbsp &nbsp </li> </div> ');     
},
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(xhr));
    },
    });
}
```